# Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma: Why is All-Defect considered a dominant strategy?

Tags: game-theory

In the finite (e.g. 100 round) Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma, sources like Wikipedia claim that All-Defect is a dominant strategy, which is then proven by backwards induction.

I understand this argument, and understand why All-Defect can be considered rational. But for it to be dominant, it must be the case that there is no better strategy given *any strategy played by the opponent*. And this seems false to me.

What if your opponent plays Tit-for-tat? It is rightly claimed that All-Defect will win against Tit-for-tat. But that seems quite irrelevant for the question of dominance, as *Tit-for-tat gains much more utility against Tit-for-tat than All-Defect does against Tit-for-tat*.

So given that my opponent plays Tit-for-tat, I would much rather play Tit-for-tat than All-Defect. Does this not mean that All-Defect isn't dominant? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Unconditional defection is indeed not a dominant strategy in the repeated Prisoner's Dilemma.